# Add CSS to static text & not dynamic in one element

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I would like to add styles to only the static text
E.G

"Hello Foo"

How Hello is created

```
      Node("td#NameID").Add(
        Hello
       )
```

Foo comes to the view through the users input using Jquery by getting the element by ID & placeing that next to Hello.

I want to have "Hello" bold, but am not sure how to do so. When I add a CSS to the ID or the class it makes the whole line bold, not just the word "Hello"

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: not sure on c# but if you create the element with a css class just add the relevant styles to your css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping Hello in a span and using css like

```
#NameID span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

As long as the Foo is outside of the span, only the "Hello" will be in bold.